# Semantic Segmentation in google colab using fastai

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, computer-vision, google-colaboratory, fast-ai

I keep getting the unsupported operand types 'str' and 'str' in my code.
I have created a dataset for semantic segmentation of sidewalk across a campus. I want to train this dataset but i am getting errors when trying to get the labels from the labeled images to map them with the input images with the function: 'get_y_fn' . I wabt to train this dataset with fastai library in google colab

```
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
%matplotlib inline

    import fastai
from fastai import *
from fastai.vision import *

import pathlib
import os
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```
fnames = get_image_files(path_img)
lbl_names = get_image_files(path_lbl)
```

```
get_y_fn = lambda x: path_lbl/f'{x.stem}.png'
data = (SegmentationItemList.from_folder(path_img)
        .random_split_by_pct()
        .label_from_func(get_y_fn,classes=codes)
        .transform(get_transforms(),size=128,tfm_y=True)
        .databunch(bs=4))
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-80efbaeba6e7> in <module>()
      2 data = (SegmentationItemList.from_folder(path_img)
      3         .split_by_rand_pct()
----> 4         .label_from_func(get_y_fn,classes=codes)
      5         .transform(get_transforms(),size=128,tfm_y=True)
      6         .databunch(bs=4))

3 frames
<ipython-input-10-44f94a438cac> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 get_y_fn = lambda x: path_lbl/f'{x.stem}.png'

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

[Program on google colab error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri84f.jpg)

[beginning of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYkiq.jpg)

Comment: 1. add more details, 2. add code not image of some random script.

Comment: Please share a self-contained link to a notebook that reproduces the problem you observe.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gfWAjLtYg677S0b1SObjxCEqiErXipJb

Comment: @BobSmith if that doesnt work can i email it too you

Comment: @MontrazOliver Please add images of your path variables for other people clarification. I went through your notebooks and answering below.

Answer (score 0):

Going through your code in google colab, I found that you've been using string as a path whereas if you're trying to reproduce fastai code then it uses path object for **paths** not string so you can simply replace:

```
get_y_fn = lambda x: path_lbl/f'{x.stem}_mask{x.suffix}'
```

with

```
get_y_fn = lambda x: path_lbl + "/" +f'{x.stem}_mask{x.suffix}'
```

Since path_lbl is a string object not path object.

You can also change path_lbl object from string to path using pathlib library of python.